# Issues displaying an emoji icon in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, emoji

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the emoji icons to display in the iPhone app I am working on. The issue is that then when someone posts something to the db from the app it gets displayed in the app as a square. What the app is getting from the server where the emojicon should be is something like this \uf604

Do anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? I have been search for a good answer but so far I haven't found anything exactly related.

```
//more info
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        self.memoArray = [returnString JSONValue]; 

//when adding it to the label
cell.memoLabel.text = [itemData objectForKey: @"memo"];
```

What I have figured out is that for example '\Uf604' needs to be '\U0001F604'.

Comment: Does the server send Json format responses? If so, what are you using to parse?

Comment: It is json. I posted a bit more info on how I parsing the json.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in Json parser SBJSON. I have been using SBJson classes, in several projects, using several versions, and found some problems with complex unicodes that are used by some Emoji chars. That icons are represented with a very long unicode, I don't remember exactly the format, but it is like a double unicode. Inside SBJson I found some bugs where it parses large unicodes.

I did modify a method and it now works, but when I went to Stig's SBJson repository to inform about that, I found an open issue about unicodes: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/issues/115

Nevertheless, my solution was very different. In the version I was using, I just had to comment in the method scanUnicodeChar: all this if with its body:

```
/*
if (hi >= 0xd800) {     // high surrogate char?
    ... if-body ... ... 
}
*/
```

If your version includes that method and that 'if', try to delete it.

For other versions, perhaps the solution is as easy. Find a method named getStringToken: and inside it, inside a switch-case '\' statement, try to comment this way:

```
/*
if (SBStringIsSurrogateHighCharacter(hi)) {
  ..... body ....
} else if ....... {
    .... ....
} else {
*/

CFStringAppendCharacters((CFMutableStringRef)acc, &hi, 1);

/*
}
*/
```

I have not tested this last one and surely something more have to be done in order to make everything work well.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow following steps:

- Convert Emoji characters to base64 and send to server.
- On server side save base64 in database without decode.
- When you want to display Emoji on Application then retrieve same base64 data from server.
- Decode retrieve string and display on app.
- Your Emoji character will display properly.

Note: When you want to Show on webPage then Decode data when you display data on WebPage.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest SBJson, this issue was fixed.

https://github.com/stig/json-framework/tags